# Logic App for Dynamic Folder creation based on the file name

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am trying to create a Folder structure dynamically based on the file name such as Year_Quarter_Month.pdf and copy the file into the targeted Folder structure \Year\Quarter\Month.pdf

Need guidance with the approach... Source FTP location, destination to OneDrive or Box folder..

Thanks
R

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage the [`split` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#split) to get the year, quarter, and month from the file name. And use the `Parse JSON` action to get these values as tokens that you can use in later actions.

Here is a snippet for how you could achieve this in your own workflow

[image: screenshot-of-logic-app-snippet]

Here is the complete Workflow JSON for reference

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Build_Path": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "path",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "@{body('Parse_JSON')?['year']}/@{body('Parse_JSON')?['quarter']}/@{body('Parse_JSON')?['month']}.@{body('Parse_JSON')?['extension']}"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Filename": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "filename",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "2020_Q3_08.pdf"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": {
                        "extension": "@{split(variables('filename'), '.')[1]}",
                        "month": "@{split(split(variables('filename'), '.')[0], '_')[2]}",
                        "quarter": "@{split(split(variables('filename'), '.')[0], '_')[1]}",
                        "year": "@{split(split(variables('filename'), '.')[0], '_')[0]}"
                    },
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "extension": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "month": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "quarter": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "year": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Filename": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you Pramod. It had solved 70-80% of the requirement, but one issue is if the # of delimiters were added for additional fields .. how to handle them ?

Comment: Could you please share an example of what you are referring to?

Comment: For Ex: There are other fields like Week & Day added to the file name such as  Year_Quarter_Month_Week_Day.pdf, and the path needs to adjusted accordingly. Also if there are situations where there are combinations of 3, 4 & 5 filed names. To be specific I was looking for generating the BuildPath Value (From u r above code) based on the array elements directly instead of variables, if at all possible. Thank you so much it really saved a ton of time for me...

Comment: Well, you could have to check for process accordingly using [conditionals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-conditional-statement) (or even [switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-switch-statement)). But as these increase, it would too much effort to maintain all of that in logic apps itself. You could instead consider [inline code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-add-run-inline-code)

Comment: Or even [offload to azure functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions)